# Eloquent model getRawOriginal() returns new values in `updating` observer

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I need to compare original model values with changes that are done when update occurs, but I am not able to do that.

My model update code looks like this:

```
 public function update(array $user, int $userId): ?bool
 {
     return User::find($userId)->update($user);
 }
```

I thought that the best way to capture changes is to use observer and observe `updating` event, because I assume it's called right before changes are stored in the database. Here is `updating` method code:

```
public function updating(User $user)
{
    Log::info('Original user', ['original' => $user->getRawOriginal('status')]);
}
```

I've tried logging a bit and it seems that `updating` method gets called after the update happens and then when I try to retrieve original model values there it returns new ones, instead of the original ones.

If I use `getChanges()` method in `updating` it returns exactly what has changed, so it seems that changes are tracked somehow, but not the original values?

Can someone give me any pointers how to solve this and explain to me why my approach doesn't work?

Update: Code, where I call `update`, is wrapped with DB transaction methods. After removing them it seems that `updating` method gets called at the right time and `getRawOriginal` then returns expected results.

In this case, what are my options? Is there a way to do what I want without removing transactions?

Comment: What about `getDirty()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can add boot method in your model .Both `updating` and `updated` trigger while updating .

```
 protected static function boot()
 {
        parent::boot(); 

        static::updating(function ($model){
            echo "updating";
            dump($model->getDirty());
            dump($model->getRawOriginal('username'));

        });

        static::updated(function ($model){
            echo "updated";
            dump($model->getDirty());
            dump($model->getRawOriginal('mobile_number'));
        });



    }
```